# Difference between 'git pull origin develop --rebase' and 'git pull --rebase origin develop'

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, rebase, pull

I couldn't find a difference but could there be one?
Between:

- option A: `git pull origin develop --rebase`
- option B: `git pull --rebase origin develop`

Git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) state :

```
git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]
```

So you would think of option B being the correct one, but than..

- why does option A also works
- and is there maybe an order by which the options are handled?

Comment: There is no difference AFAIK.  As to _why_, Git syntax is often very lax, that's why.

Comment: No, the position of options is irrelevant in git. Just beware of `--` in some commands, because everything after it is considered filepaths. `git show --name-only abcd1234 -- path/to/file.txt` will not be equivalent to `git show abcd1234 -- path/to/file.txt --name-only`

Comment: @RomainValeri aha, so we'd prefer option A than

Comment: @MRedant No. If you want to prevent unexpected mistakes, prefer option B like it is described in the documentation. It is a shared convention between most of the unix command line tools...

Comment: thx @RomainValeri if you post this as an answer I can mark it as a solution

Comment: @MRedant I'm quite surprised by your comment, since I did not propose *any* answer nor solution in my first comment. I was merely pointing out that *no option* should be put after `--` which is the symbol for "everything past this are filepaths". And here you do *not* use `--` in your command, sorry if I somehow added confusion. Also, I have no clue why you got that my comment prompted you towards what you call "option A".

Comment: @RomainValeri .. sorry for the confusion.. I was refering to the 'No' in your first comment and the other interesting background-info you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are competing theories on how rigid one should be with placement of options vs arguments.  POSIX [utility guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) prescribe what you called Option B.  Git, however, tries to be quite flexible about option placement, even when there are optional or required positional arguments.

These are the general rules for Git options:

- Options placed *between* `git` and the sub-command verb, such as `git --no-replace-objects log`, are handled by the Git front end (the `git` program itself).  The front end transforms these into environment variable settings, which means that there's always an environment variable you could set instead.  For instance:

  ```
   git --git-dir=<path> ...
  ```

  and

  ```
   GIT_DIR=<path> git ...
  ```

  do the same thing.

  Options placed *after* the sub-command verb are handled by the sub-command.
- Single-letter options, such as `-v`, are preceded by a single hyphen, and can be grouped together.  Multi-letter options, such as `--name-status`, are preceded by a double hyphen.  Hence in `git diff`, there is a `-c` option ("combined diffs") but also a `--cc` option ("dense combined diffs"); the single-c option takes a single dash and the double-c option takes a double dash.
- Anything starting with a hyphen is an option, anywhere, *except* after a double-hyphen.

The `git filter-branch` command breaks the last rule a bit because it has to parse its own options, then pass some options to `git rev-list`.  So with filter-branch, you run:

```
git filter-branch <filter-options> -- <rev-list-options>
```

and the `<rev-list-options>` itself can have options, then a second stand-alone double hyphen `--`, then path names.<sup>1</sup>

This all adds up to what you called Option A.  But note that if you write your commands with Option B in mind, they all *work* under Option A.

> and is there maybe an order by which the options are handled?

There were, in the past, for some Git sub-commands, some places where order was particularly important.  That's fixed now but you will see this remark in [the `git checkout-index` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index):

> The order of the flags used to matter, but not anymore.

In general, however, options are processed in the order they appear, and often, a repeated option will overwrite a previous one.  For instance:

```
git --git-dir=/tmp --git-dir=.git status
```

uses `.git` as the Git directory, not `/tmp`.

---

<sup>1</sup>By *can* here, I mean *is physically able to*.  You shouldn't actually *use* this capacity with `git filter-branch` as it is a form of aiming a gun at your own foot.